How to Test and Implement Industry and Year Fixed Effects vs. POLS in Panel Data Analysis?
I am new to econometric modelling.
I am working with panel data spanning 8 years, including 155 units (REITs) distributed across 8 different industries. I aim to apply industry fixed effects and year fixed effects but not entity fixed effects. How can I implement this correctly in R?
When testing whether to use fixed effects or pooled ordinary least squares, how should I set up my POLS model? Should I include factor(YEAR) and factor(INDUSTRY) in the POLS model to test whether POLS is preferable over FE, or should these not be included for this purpose?
Below, I have outlined the models I am currently using. However, I am uncertain whether I am testing correctly and proceeding in the right way. How can I determine whether I should use industry fixed effects rather than entity fixed effects?
FE_model_H1TSR <- plm(TSR ~ LOG_ESG + LOG_TA + GTA + LOG_AGE, data = pdata, model = "within", index= c("INDUSTRY","YEAR"), effects = "twoway")
Pols_model_H1TSR <- plm(TSR ~ LOG_ESG + GTA + LOG_AGE + LOG_TA + factor(YEAR) + factor(INDUSTRY) , data = pdata, model = "pooling")
